# How to change Jquery code to JS code in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am new to JS and Jquery . I am downloaded a html,css,js code from codeSandbox. I replaced this code as ReactJs code. But i don't know how to change this Jquery code. Pls Help me. Here i am sharing the code.

```
$(".hamburger").click(function(){
   $(".wrapper").toggleClass("collapse");
});
```

Here is the codeSandbox url

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-bohr-vxlvq?file=/src/Layout.js
```

Comment: where do you want to add that css?

Comment: in app.css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution. [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-star-mm50v?file=/src/Layout.js)

Please check this and *DON'T USE JQUERY WITH REACT*